# image repository with noise for testing

Tags: testing, image-processing

I need set of gray scale images with random noise to do some testing.

I have searched and found many images but without noise.

Or maybe some easy way to add a random noise to an image.

Comment: Adding noise is very easy yourself. Additionally, you will have a "controlled environment" so to speak with knows noise distribution. I usually just do it manually.

Comment: "Noise" is a too general term. You may think what kind of noise you want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For image processing you could use [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) which is a great image processing tool (There are another alternatives like Photoshop and Paint Shop Pro).

Also, if you want to add the noise programatically you should state what environment are you working with so we can help you.